# Cookie for the entire website?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm pretty confused, it's the first time I use cookies and it doesn't work as well.

```
setcookie('remember', $user->id . '==' . $remember_token . sha1($user->id . 'dingdangdong'), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,"/");
```

So here is my code which is supposed to create a cookie - it does but **only in the folder "login" where the file is situated** (*it took me 24hours to discover that*). So I'm searching for a solution to set the cookie for the entire website and I found guys who said to add the **"/"** at the end or the "domain.com" but nothing work fine.

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: I do not use "/" at the end and it works everywhere on my website

Comment: I don't understand why so, because it works everywhere in my /login/ folder (it's a "remember-me" cookie)  but when i'm in the root -> no cookie

Comment: It seems as you are building a string inside the setcookie. Maybe... that is the problem, create a $value that you build outside and se if that helps. Sha1 is a function? That could be a reason/problem

Comment: So you set the cookie in a subfolder? Is it possible to move that to the root?

Comment: Besides the path / you should also set 5 argument domain `setcookie('remember', $user->id . '==' . $remember_token . sha1($user->id . 'dingdangdong'), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,"/", "yourdomain.com");`

Comment: Thanks Denis it works !

Answer (score 0):

as said in [documentation of setcookie method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) besides the path "/" you should also set the fifth argument "domain"
`setcookie('remember', $user->id . '==' . $remember_token . sha1($user->id . 'dingdangdong'), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,"/", "yourdomain.com");`